# How to display continue popup with adb debug

Tags: android, adb

I use the adb command to invoke the app process and waiting for debug connection from the IDE (Visual Studio with AGDE).
When I start the command `adb shell am start -n "com.example.hellojni/.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -D`
Sometime the app on device/emulator display the Popup with `Continue` and `Force Close` buttons, but usually it display the `Force Close` button
Do you know how to always display the `Continue` button?  [image]
Thanks

UPDATE:
I was mistaken between the Emulator. The Firmware 7 has `Continue Run` popup. So the question is: How to display `Continue Run` popup on Firmware 9 and above.
[image]

Comment: I didn't see any code about "Continue"  in AppWaitingForDebuggerDialog

Comment: I just update the post - the firmware 7 has Continue popup.